# Problem running dotnet core app in lambda as container image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a docker image that I want to deploy as a lambda function (running C# .net core 3.1)

The exact steps I'm doing are:

- i'm cloning [this](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/blank-csharp) example repo
- in the `src/blank-csharp` folder I add the following Dockerfile that uses the [official](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet) dotnet core 3.1 image.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:core3.1.2022.08.18.10

COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD [ "blank-csharp::blankCsharp.Function::FunctionHandler" ]
```

- I build the image `docker build -t dotnet-container:latest .`
- I spin up the container `docker run -p 9000:8080 dotnet-container:latest`
- I try to call the lambda function with `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"payload":"hello world!"}'`

However, this results in the error

```
{
  "errorType": "LambdaException",
  "errorMessage": "Could not find the required 'blank-csharp.deps.json'.  This file should be present at the root of the deployment package."
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: What OS are you running this on? Cannot reproduce on Mac OS.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Mac OS Monterey on Macbook M1

Comment: Likewise but on an Intel Mac - I can't seem to reproduce this unfortunately

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary So you tried and were able to successfully run the container?